# Return html from variable into value of react <input />

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a function that converts 2/3 into ⅔ (`&frac23;`) dynamically and return it into the value of an input using react.

Here is what I have so far:

```
toFraction(str) {
    // Convert string '2/4' into '&frac24;
    return newStr     // &frac24;
}

<input type="text" value={this.toFraction(quantity)} />
```

However, react is rendering the html code as a string instead of the actual fraction.

Is there a way to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML for the value of an input?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Aside from being aware of the **[JSX Gotchas](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)**, what you need to do for your function to be effective is to map your fractions to corresponding UTF-8 or HTML entities, otherwise you will not be able to make your function work correctly. Does that make sense? Unless you are simply looking to convert 2/4... rather 1/2 into its HTML entity, then its a one case scenario you can overcome via the provided link

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you are using utf-8 encoding, you can avoid using `&frac23;` and just insert `⅔`, `¼`, or any character you need directly, without character encoding.

This means you can avoid dangerously setting your HTML, since the string will be the proper value string.

Here is the JSX gotcha documentation from React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html. "There are various ways to work-around this issue. The easiest one is to write Unicode characters directly in JavaScript. You need to make sure that the file is saved as UTF-8 and that the proper UTF-8 directives are set so the browser will display it correctly."

Comment: My only issue with this solution is that I'll be generating these fractions dynamically so creating &frac23; seems a lot more efficient than writing some sort of check for every type of function.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually one of the ["JSX Gotchas" in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities).

> If you want to display an HTML entity within dynamic content, you will run into double escaping issues as React escapes all the strings you are displaying in order to prevent a wide range of XSS attacks by default.

It gives three possible solutions:

1. Just use the UTF-8 character, rather than the entity. `<div>⅔</div>`
2. Use the [corresponding unicode number for the entity](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/): `<div>{'stuff \u224C more stuff'}</div>` or `String.fromCharCode(someNum)`.
3. And, most dangerously, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '&frac24;'}} />`